# How do I show the sum of all dynamic radio input values after I click on it in a specific result div by using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter-3

This is my last post here in this coder's community because I ask this in many ways but didn't get the proper solution. So I simplify my code and paste it here again. I'm not so good in jquery/js so that is why I'm stuck with this code.

**Please help me, It'll be great help for me because this is my first project and I just moved from a banking sector to programming world. Thanks in advance for all your efforts and help.**

Following is the code where I mentioned the static version of html part(it is dynamically coming from database).

```js
var matched = $('.option_yes');
var countedItem = matched.length;

//This code is for the example purpose to show the value when hit on radio button
$(document).on('click', '.extraRoomOption:checked', function(e){
   //$('#p'+i+'_price').html($(this).val());
   alert($(this).val());
});

//This is the rubished(Because I wrote this) code that will be use in production:
var i;
for(i = 1; i <= countedItem; i++){
  $('input[name=extraRoom'+i+']').on('click', function(e){
    if($(e.target).is('#extraRoomInput_y'+i)){
      $('#p'+i+'_price').html($(this).val());
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Maggie's room type</h3>
<p>would you like your own room?</p>
<label>
  <input type="radio" class="extraRoomOption option_yes" name="extraRoom1" id="y1_extraRoomInput" value="150000">
  <b>Yes, please</b>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" class="extraRoomOption option_no" name="extraRoom1" id="n1_extraRoomInput" value="125000" checked>
  <b>No, thanks</b>
</label>

<hr>

<h3>Esther's room type</h3>
<p>would you like your own room?</p>
<label>
  <input type="radio" class="extraRoomOption option_yes" name="extraRoom2" id="y2_extraRoomInput" value="150000">
  <b>Yes, please</b>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" class="extraRoomOption option_no" name="extraRoom2" id="n2_extraRoomInput" value="125000" checked>
  <b>No, thanks</b>
</label>

<br>
<hr><hr>

<h2>Room type</h2>
<p>Maggie (Twin Room) And Price is <span id="p1_price">125000</span></p>
<p>Esther (Twin Room) And Price is <span id="p2_price">125000</span></p>
<p><b>Total Price is <span id="totalPrice">250000</span></b></p>
```

> **Ignore this if you don't want to know about how my website is working.**
>  
>  
>   Let me explain first how my website should be work :
>  
>   1) When a user come to my website and click on tour and then fill booking form with his basic personal information.
>  
>   2) After that all information will be save into the database and then the **tailor your trip page** appear just after the first step. 
>   3) Now this is the tricky part where I'm stuck. When user click on **Room type option** it should work like: The price of the selected passenger would be update automatically and then sum of all passenger's price should be show in final price box. 
>   4) Here are the my previous question link:
>
> > [Show sum of the dynamic price when click on radio button in jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58048852/show-sum-of-the-dynamic-price-when-click-on-radio-button-in-jquery)
> >     
> >     
> >     [Show sum of dynamic radio input element and It should also show when click on another radio input element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58046863/show-sum-of-dynamic-radio-input-element-and-it-should-also-show-when-click-on-an)
>
> 5) See the picture below:
>   [image: Workflow of my website]

Comment: What is your issue exactly? What does console says? Any errors?

Comment: see here is my page where I want to show the sum of option selected by the user : https://www.incredibleindiantours.com/book/additionalServicesConfirmation/25/V3NkK3UweTJBWjNhdTR4OWo1VmFvUT09/classic-golden-triangle.html

Comment: I don't see anything dynamic in the link you posted...

Comment: PS don't use `click`... it's not wrong, just by historical reasons the click handlers work. Instead use the `"change"` event when handling `radio` or `checkbox` type elements.

Comment: If you see there is two passengers and I'm trying to get the sum of the total of each passengers room type price and show the final price in right hand side price box.

Comment: The passengers are static. There's nothing dynamic.

Comment: You come from banking to programming, yet I don't see in any place in your code where you iterate over the checked elements and **sum** the values...

Comment: You are partially right. But when someone try to book any trip then he can be able to add many of passenger with him. Here is the booking form : https://www.incredibleindiantours.com/book/tour/25/classic-golden-triangle.html

Comment: OK, but on *"Continue"* you generate a new page... With all static elements. You just need to update a SUM value on Checkbox change...

Comment: I don't get the logic... Say I have three persons, two rooms... what logic tells that two persons are listed for a specific room and the third for the other?

Comment: I did this because I want to save the passenger list into the database. The page you saw after hit click on continue, All data of passenger came from database and it is the demand of my client :(

Comment: I know this is silly but it is the demand of my client :(

Comment: I really don't get the website booking logic... I can have N persons, N rooms.... yet I should calculate some XY price... what? Sorry but this cannot be done having tat many unknown variables. You should state in your question what is you true intent with those calculations or you'll be back here soon again asking for improvement on a broken logic.....

Comment: This booking form is for group tour of different persons.

Comment: Please explain. Your exact case, I have two travelers, I tick the first radio button on "SHARE ROOM" for the first room and I do the same for the other room. Should the website explode? Or should the price top up to actually 4 persons? Makes absolutely no sense. Leaving this question, I'm afraid I'm taking too much effort on commenting instead of answering

Comment: Well again thanks for all your effort and help. I drop the idea of showing total amount/price of each passenger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code might be helpful... I have added `data-target` attribute to target particular price with ID.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $(document).on('click', '.extraRoomOption:checked', function(e){
  var targetPrice = $(this).data('target');
  $('#'+targetPrice).text($(this).val());
  
  grandTotal();
 });

 function grandTotal(){
  var total = 0;
  $('.extraRoomOption:checked').each(function(e){
   total += parseFloat($(this).val());
  });
  $('#totalPrice').text(total);
 }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>Maggie's room type</h3>
<p>would you like your own room?</p>
<label>
  <input type="radio" class="extraRoomOption option_yes" name="extraRoom1" id="y1_extraRoomInput" data-target="p1_price" value="150000">
  <b>Yes, please</b>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" class="extraRoomOption option_no" name="extraRoom1" id="n1_extraRoomInput" value="125000" data-target="p1_price" checked>
  <b>No, thanks</b>
</label>

<hr>

<h3>Esther's room type</h3>
<p>would you like your own room?</p>
<label>
  <input type="radio" class="extraRoomOption option_yes" name="extraRoom2" id="y2_extraRoomInput" data-target="p2_price" value="150000">
  <b>Yes, please</b>
</label>
<label>
  <input type="radio" class="extraRoomOption option_no" name="extraRoom2" id="n2_extraRoomInput" value="125000" data-target="p2_price" checked>
  <b>No, thanks</b>
</label>

<br>
<hr><hr>

<h2>Room type</h2>
<p>Maggie (Twin Room) And Price is <span id="p1_price">125000</span></p>
<p>Esther (Twin Room) And Price is <span id="p2_price">125000</span></p>
<p><b>Total Price is <span id="totalPrice">250000</span></b></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the form tag (It is easier to work with input fields with it). Please note the html code is almost the same as from your example, only the form tag was added.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var form = document.getElementById('radio-form');
  var inputs = form.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]');

  var p1 = document.getElementById('p1_price');
  var p2 = document.getElementById('p2_price');
  var total = document.getElementById('totalPrice');

  function setPrice() {
    var room1 = form.elements['extraRoom1'];
    var room2 = form.elements['extraRoom2'];

    p1.innerHTML = room1.value;
    p2.innerHTML = room2.value;
    total.innerHTML = +room1.value + +room2.value;
  };

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
    input.addEventListener('change', setPrice);
  });

  setPrice();
});
```

```html
<h3>Maggie's room type</h3>
<p>would you like your own room?</p>
<form id="radio-form">
  <label>
      <input type="radio" class="extraRoomOption option_yes" name="extraRoom1" id="y1_extraRoomInput" value="150000">
      <b>Yes, please</b>
    </label>
  <label>
      <input type="radio" class="extraRoomOption option_no" name="extraRoom1" id="n1_extraRoomInput" value="125000" checked>
      <b>No, thanks</b>
    </label>

  <hr>

  <h3>Esther's room type</h3>
  <p>would you like your own room?</p>
  <label>
      <input type="radio" class="extraRoomOption option_yes" name="extraRoom2" id="y2_extraRoomInput" value="150000">
      <b>Yes, please</b>
    </label>
  <label>
      <input type="radio" class="extraRoomOption option_no" name="extraRoom2" id="n2_extraRoomInput" value="125000" checked>
      <b>No, thanks</b>
    </label>
</form>

<br>
<hr>
<hr>

<h2>Room type</h2>
<p>Maggie (Twin Room) And Price is <span id="p1_price">125000</span></p>
<p>Esther (Twin Room) And Price is <span id="p2_price">125000</span></p>
<p><b>Total Price is <span id="totalPrice">250000</span></b></p>
```

Correct the code if necessary. I hope I helped you.

Comment: sorry but there is some error in your code. But still thank you so much for all your efforts and help.

Comment: PS: regarding `Array.prototype.forEach.call(inputs,`... NodeList has by default the `.forEach` method embedded - unless you're targeting some really ancient browsers like IE you can go for `myNodes.forEach(` directly.